# floor() returning different results

Tags: sql-server

In the following code, `floor()` (in the 3rd param of the `iif()`) does not return `100` as expected; it returns `100.00`. I am just testing the output and the logic, hence the hard coded values.

```
select iif(floor(100.000) < cast(round(100.000, 2) as decimal(5, 2)), cast(round(100.000, 2) as decimal(5, 2)), floor(100.000))
```

However this indeed returns `100` as expected. I am not sure why:

```
select floor(100.000)
```

Further, back to the `iif()` function: If I first cast the value inside the floor function to a `float`, it indeed returns `100`. I have tried casting it to an `integer` and a `decimal` as well and `floor()` still returns `100.00`. This really has thrown me. I was under the impression that `floor` will only return anything after the decimal if it is of type `money`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs on `IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql):

> Returns the data type with the highest precedence from the types in true_value and false_value

And the [rules on data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql):

> When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher precedence

Since the `true_value` part of your expression returns a `decimal`, the entire expression will do the same.

To use a simpler example:

```
SELECT IIF(0 > 0,
        CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(5, 2)),
        2)
```

This will cause the `2` to be cast to a `decimal`.

Comment: Technically, [FLOOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/floor-transact-sql) returns the same type as the numeric expression, so the false_value part of the IIF function, "floor(100.000)", is also returning a decimal.

Comment: @Anssssss While you're right that it returns a `decimal`, it returns one of different precision and scale in this case. `100.00` is determined to be a `decimal(6, 0)` which still causes the data type precedence to matter

Comment: Ok, that makes sense and I should have checked the docs on iif(). However, to my defence, I put the same logic in a Case When statement and got the same results and in my mind, ruled out anything funky that iif() was doing. Cheers!